# Signs in states which say "Only Trash Litters"

Tags: american-english, signage

In many states I can see signs posted which state
"Only Trash Litters" which I certainly have no problem understanding
and which appear to be correct usage to me. "Trash" can be singular or plural so
I have no problem about this. If the s is dropped on "litters" would both be correct? Or is one use correct?

Comment: As someone from the UK it actually took me a few moments to understand this phrase (I've never come across it before); went through a few alternative readings such as "Only destroy groups of cats' offspring" before hitting on the right meaning :)

Comment: And Trash is more commonly used as a verb, So "only trash memory you allocate" was the sense I got.

Answer (score 5):

"Trash" in this instance, besides being a play on words, in one of its meanings may be construed as a collective noun. Collective nouns may use singular or plural verbs.

Without the use of the singular here, the double meaning wouldn't work. It would be reduced to a single-entendre.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, most people have no problem whatsoever understanding that a sign that reads "Only trash litters" is correct and refers to a person that would litter is trash or trashy. Litters is the singular form to use. The gist is easy.

Answer (score 0):

If trash were singular then "Only trash litters" would be "Only he/she litters" which is correct. If it were plural then "Only they litters" wouldn't be.

Presumably anybody who cared about this level of grammatical detail wouldn't litter so it's not really a problem.